# Problem to get the right Id in lightning component

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, salesforce-id

In my lightning component I have a list of object like that :

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:attribute name="idArt" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="articles" type="Article__c[]"/>
<aura:registerEvent name="navigate" type="c:X_ArticleToDetailEvent"/>

<ul class="list-group">
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.articles}" var="article">
      <li class="list-group-item">
          <a href="{! '#articleId=' + article.Id }" onclick="{!c.toDetail}" data-recId="{!article.Id}">
              <p>{!article.Name}</p>
              <p>{!article.Prix__c}</p>
              <p>{!article.Id}</p>
              <input type="hidden" value="{!article.Id}" name="idarticle" />
          </a>
      </li>
  </aura:iteration>
</ul>
```

I want that when I click on the link, I open another component with the informations about the selected item. 
Here is the controller js :

```
doInit : function(component, event) {
    //selectionne tous les articles
    var action = component.get("c.findAll");
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        component.set("v.articles", a.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

toDetail : function(component, event, helper) {
    var id = event.target.getAttribute("data-recId");
    console.log("id : " + id);
    var evt = $A.get("e.c:X_ArticleToDetailEvent");
    evt.setParams({ "idArticle": id});
    evt.fire();
}
```

I can see the list, and if I click on a link It redirect me to the second component, but the id of the selected item is most of the time null (I can see it in the console log) and then obviously the informations in the second component are not displayed. 
(And sometimes the id is not null and the second component is displayed correctly... )

Do you have an idea of why I get that behaviour ?

Comment: your code seems fine. I'm not sure what is happening.One question, do you have another `onclick="{!c.toDetail}"` in your code apart from the anchor tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Rao pointed out, you are clicking on the `<p />` tags wrapped within the anchor, and thus causing the `event.target.getattribute('data-recId')` to return `null`.

```
<a href="{! '#articleId=' + article.Id }" onclick="{!c.toDetail}" data-recId="{!article.Id}">
              <p>{!article.Name}</p>
              <p>{!article.Prix__c}</p>
              <p>{!article.Id}</p>
              <input type="hidden" value="{!article.Id}" name="idarticle" />
          </a>
```

You might wonder why this is happening, even though `onclick` was fired properly?

It's due to **event bubbling**. In simple term, when you click on the `<p/>` tag, the *event* generated will bubble up the DOM Node and fires onclick(if found) on the its parent,grandparent...etc.

In your case, there's only one parent tag with `onclick` registered which is the anchor tag, so `toDetail()` is executed by the **event bubbling** process. you can find more info about bubbling [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing).

```
<a href="{! '#articleId=' + article.Id }" onclick="{!c.toDetail}" data-recId="{!article.Id}">
```

So, the `event.target` => **points to `<p />` tag where the click originated**.

To solve this problem, we have to use
 `event.currentTarget` => **points to tag where event handler(eg:onclick) was registered.**

So, changing your method to below would solve the issue:

```
toDetail : function(component, event, helper) {
    var id = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-recId");
    console.log("id : " + id);
    var evt = $A.get("e.c:X_ArticleToDetailEvent");
    evt.setParams({ "idArticle": id});
    evt.fire();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Praveen for the answer, I better understand the way it works then, and this solution works fine !

Answer (score 2):

I think the way you applied the anchor tag is causing this issue. The anchor tag has been applied for the below 4 lines.

```
<a href="{! '#articleId=' + article.Id }" onclick="{!c.toDetail}" data-recId="{!article.Id}">
              <p>{!article.Name}</p>
              <p>{!article.Prix__c}</p>
              <p>{!article.Id}</p>
              <input type="hidden" value="{!article.Id}" name="idarticle" />
          </a>
```

The first  tag has no label so you cannot click on anything. When you click on the rest the data-recid is null and hence your controller is throwing null when the `event.target.getattribute('data-recId')` is called.

2 options

1) close the anchor tag before the `<p>{!article.Name}</p>` and provide a label for the anchor.

2) apply the data-recId="{!article.Id}" for all

elements inside the   tag. when you click on one of the links the Id gets passed to the JS controller.

```
<a href="{! '#articleId=' + article.Id }" onclick="{!c.toDetail}" data-recId="{!article.Id}">

<p data-recId="{!article.Id}">{!article.Name}</p>
<p data-recId="{!article.Id}">{!article.Prix__c}</p>
<p data-recId="{!article.Id}">{!article.Id}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly, I mark @Praveen 's answers as the right since there some explanations but your solution is right too.

Comment: @dou no problem, all that matters is you got a solution. It was a good learning excercise for me too. I went next step and created a notifier component that posts the output when the event fires and played around a little more with lightning :)